# How to use a value that came out of select statement in an insert

Tags: sql, postgresql, max, sql-insert

## What I am trying to do

On an insert of a form I want to check if the form doesn't already exists.
If it exists I want to give the insert a higher versionnumber.

So I thought I could get the highest versionnumber of the form im trying to insert use that in the insert statement + 1.

But it doesn't work and I can't get it to work

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION check_form_insert()
RETURNS trigger
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
BEGIN

    IF (SELECT EXISTS(
        SELECT *
        FROM form
        WHERE (name = NEW.name)
        )
    )
    THEN
        SELECT f.versionnumber
        FROM form f
        WHERE CONCAT(versionnumber, f.name) in (
            SELECT CONCAT(MAX(versionnumber), name)
            FROM form
            GROUP BY name
        ) AND name = NEW.name;

        INSERT INTO form (versionnumber, name, state, timestamp)
        VALUES(
            f.versionnumber + 1,
            NEW.name,
            1,
            NOW()
        );


    END IF;
    RETURN null;
END;
$$;
```

Comment: What if the form does not yet exists, what do you want to do in that case?

Comment: Then it should create a form with versionnumber 1.
But I haven't implemented that yet because I could get this to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in a single `insert ... select` statement:

```
insert into form (versionnumber, name, state, timestamp)
select coalesce(max(versionnumber), 0) + 1, $1, 1, now()
from form
where name = $1;
```

The logic is to search for the last version number of the form in the table (with a default of `0`), and increment it.

`$1` is the parameter to the query, that should be given the form name. I doubt that you need a trigger to do what you want.